# Change in behaviour of toLabel() function in SOQL query for Knowledge__DataCategorySelection

Tags: bug

There has been a change in behaviour of toLabel() function in SOQL for Knowledge__DataCategorySelection object's DataCategoryName field after Summer 23 release for Salesforce.

**Before the Summer 2023 Release Update**
The toLabel() function in SOQL query for the Object Knowledge__DataCategorySelection when used to convert the results of a field "DataCategoryName" into the user’s language i.e. remove the Underscores between two words OR convert to the label value used to work in correct way.

Resultant Value Label = "Program Information", Resultant Value = "Program_Information"

Expected Output(label): "Program Information"
Actual Output(label): "Program Information"

**After the Summer 2023 Release Update**
The toLabel() function in the SOQL query for the Object Knowledge__DataCategorySelection is returning the wrong results with underscores between two words for the field DataCategoryName.

Resultant Value Label = "Program Information", Resultant Value = "Program_Information"

Expected Output: "Program Information"
Actual Output: "Program_Information"

Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: Yes, I am experiencing the same issue. Using tolabel() will bring a mix of values with underscore and without underscore. It's not sticking to the Category Name as I'd like but is instead sometimes getting the Category Unique Name.

If I bump up the API version of the code or the URL for the REST call then it works as expected.